# Routing Error when trying to access a linkother than the baseURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, controller

I have a "routing" problem on CodeIgniter 4.2.7.

My home page is displayed well, the page also reloads well when I click on "home" in my menu, on this side there is no problem, however when I want to access another page I have the message error following "Error 404".

Here is my controller:

```
class c_accueil extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['titre'] = "Accueil";
        return
            view('v_menu')
            . view('v_accueil',$data)
            . view('v_footer');
    }
    public function espaceNintendo()
    {
        $data['titre'] = "Espace Nintendo";
        return
            view('v_menu')
            . view('v_espaceNintendo', $data)
            . view('v_footer');
    }
```

Here is my base url:

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:63342/ProjetWeb';
```

Here is my route:

```
$routes->get('/', 'c_accueil::index');$routes->get('/public/espaceNintendo', 'c_accueil::espaceNintendo');
```

Here is my view (v_menu) :

```
<?=anchor(base_url().'/public/', 'Accueil')?>
<?=anchor(base_url().'/public/espaceNintendo', 'Espace Nintendo')?>
```

So "Accueil" works fine but not "espaceNintendo"

Url of my home page which works well:

http://localhost:63342/ProjetWeb/public/

However, the URL as soon as I click on "Espace nintendo" is this:

http://localhost:63342/ProjetWeb/public/espaceNintendo

But it gives me "error 404".

Do you have any idea where the problem comes from?

My helpers are well loaded on my base_controller:

```
protected $helpers = ['html', 'form', 'url'];
```